# Можно ли создать класс по ссылке на него?

Tags: классы, kotlin

Могу получить ссылку на класс вот таким образом:

```
class MyClass() {}

val link = MyClass::class
```

Можно ли теперь как-то создать экземпляр класса с помощью ссылки на него?

Должно получиться примерно вот так:

```
val myClass: MyClass = link()
```

К примеру, в PHP есть такая возможность. Интересно, как это работает здесь? И если здесь так нельзя, то зачем вообще оно нужно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val link = ::MyClass
val myClass = link()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
val myClass = (MyClass)link.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()
```